# With Nexus, should I use nuget or a different repo type for application binaries?

Tags: nuget, nexus

My company is mostly a Linux based company and we use Nexus. We have setup a nuget repository for our C# group within Nexus, but my question is should I be using the Maven repository type (or another type) to store our release binary applications of a .net/console/service fabric applications for internal consumption or should I package this as a Nuget application? I'm not talking about shared libraries which we will use Nuget for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have another application to store released versions of non-maven project artifacts, you can create a repo as maven repository and upload the artifacts with GAV parameters.